# How do I count the total number of lines of code I wrote in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I wrote an application in VB.NET and since I charge by the line, I would like to calculate how many lines I wrote. I have about 100 different Visual Basic files with my code. How do I count all the lines?

Comment: You have clients that are willing to pay you by the line of code written??

Comment: I think this is a problematic question. Just to make a point, how many lines of code is this: function foofoo() { /// just a comment int x=1; return; } is this 3, 5, 7?

Comment: "I charge by the line" - That's a really bad idea. That's like charging for a military aircraft by how much it weighs or a doctor charging for surgery by how much it hurts you.

Comment: My supplier charges by the line, not by the kilo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a regex search for a line-break char that isn't followed by another linebreak (excluding blank lines)

Alternatively there's this app http://cloc.sourceforge.net/ (I haven't used it, I just found it)

Answer (score 3):

On the command line:

```
(for /r %x in (*.vb) do @type "%x") | find /v /c ""
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005) or earlier then there's [a line counter add-in at WndTabs.com](http://www.wndtabs.com).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

1. [Example 1](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2007/04/23/14050.aspx)
2. [Example 2](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/CountingLinesOfSourceCodeInPowerShell.aspx)

I also recommend the excellent [NDepends](http://www.ndepend.com/) suite as well. For one, I think it will clearly illustrate why lines of code is a very difficult thing to measure, and not necessarily a good measure of quality, or amount of work in a codebase.

Answer (score 1):

[Line Counter on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lcounter/) is a VB.NET application that counts the lines for you in your application. I was going to say you could write your own VB.NET application to do this, but luckily it has already been done. It's sweet how the Internet works that way.

Also, charging by the line?  Newline must be your friend!  LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I really hope you're joking about charging by the line, but if not, there are a number of prepackaged free utilities and scripts that will do these sort of quick-and-dirty metrics for you, like the **[Line Count Utility](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/lcamlibel/LineCount04212005061925AM/LineCount.aspx)**.

P.S. Please consider a different way of charging your customers!

Answer (score -1):

On a Unix-like platform:

```
 find . -name *.vb | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: VB.NET usually doesn't imply a *nix-y platform :-)

Comment: No, but Autopulated is probably wondering (as I am) why it's such a problem to count the number of lines in a bunch of files. I imagine the Powershell solution is similarly concise.

Answer (score -1):

I have just come up to this question myself. Although this is a 10 yr old question.
Well try this, on your VB.NET, just go to ANALYZE menu and just click Calculate Code Metrics for your project and your done. :)