# Count Lines, Characters/Words in a VB Project?

Tags: vb.net

Simply put; Is there anything built into Visual Basic 2013 that counts the amount of lines, characters or words in a VB.net Project? I'm refer to the programming code of that project including forms, objects and classes.

Similar to the word count in Word Processors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977660/how-do-i-count-the-total-number-of-lines-of-code-i-wrote-in-vb-net and http://sourceforge.net/projects/lcounter/ (I haven't used this, so I don't know how reliable it would be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get lines of code and other information (but not characters or words) using the [Code Metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx) in Visual Studio.  This returns:

- Maintainability Index
- Cyclomatic Complexity
- Depth of Inheritance
- Class Coupling
- Lines of Code

You can execute this by going to the **Analyze** menu and selecting **Calculate Code Metrics for Solution**. This requires Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate.